# Does the Embed.ly WordPress Plug-in Work with hosted Wordpress.com sites or only with self-hosted WP?

Tags: wordpress

I can't tell from their Support, FAQ and Documentation page. It if allowed embeds to work inside of Wordpress.com sites, that would be astoundingly cool. Thanks!

Comment: You should contact the plugin author to confirm. This question is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Why is it off topic? I contacted them and they were slow to respond so I thought I would ask here. Could you explain why it's off topic? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, sadly the plugin only works on self hosted Wordpress installs.